# how to access parent component methods in child component like below example

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
//this is the parent component in ibios.js file

import  React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class ibios extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
        super();
        this.sate={};
        this.get = this.get.bind(this);
    }
 get(ur,apiurl,prametars){
  prametars=prepareHeaderRequest;
    return axios.get(url+apiUrl,{params:prametars})
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>hi...</p>
            );
   }
}

//this is the child component chart component.js file

import React from 'react';
import ibios from '../ibios/IBIOS';
import ChartComponent from './chartcomponents';

class BarChartComponent extends ChartComponent{
  constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={};  
    }
   componentDidMount(){
      //example
       var url="http://localhost:9090",apiUrl="/reports",prametrs={xyz:ramki};
     var retriveResponse=this.ibios.get(url,apiUrl,prametrs)
     console.log(retriveResponse);
   }
  render(){
     return(<p>hi......</p>);
  }
}
```

// i have write axios method only once in ibos.js and how to inherit every componet and how to get response directily through ibos.get()?....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

```js
class First extends React.Component {
  first() {
    alert("First")
  }
  render() {
    return <div>sdfsdf</div>
  }
}

class Second extends First {
  second() {
    alert('Second')
  }
  render() {
    return <div>dsfsdfsdf</div>
  }
}

class Third extends Second {
  onButtonClick() {
    super.second()
    super.first()
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() =>     {this.onButtonClick()}}>Hello</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Third />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

```
You should extend 'ibios' class instead of Chart Component in your child component and use keyword 'super' to use parent methods.  Otherwise you can send it as props and use it

    class BarChartComponent extends Ibios{
      constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state={};  
        }
       componentDidMount(){
          //example
           var url="http://localhost:9090",apiUrl="/reports",prametrs={xyz:ramki};
         var retriveResponse=super.get(url,apiUrl,prametrs)
         console.log(retriveResponse);
       }
      render(){
         return(<p>hi......</p>);
      }
    }
```

Comment: sorry if you don't mind could you please tell me how to extends multiple class in one component

Comment: you can extend class 'ibios' with 'chartComponent' class.  And so extending 'BarChartComponent' with 'ibios' will help you to inherit both of those classes

Comment: I have added a sample snippet implementing this..Pls refer

Comment: if functions have call ok but my intention is how to inherit axios methods how get response directily

Comment: Keep your axios function in a separate common file and call that function wherever you want

Comment: Keep your axios function in a separate common file and call that function wherever you want please send one example